# Offline storage management for android

Tags: java, android, offline, offline-caching

```
Theme : Newspaper updates in android application.
```

How to fetch or retrieve data from server and post updates on android application . How to manage offline storage means whenever there is no internet connection how the data gone be updated on android application , atleast how it consider showing updates on android application . If any one known this issue please answer about it .

I am actually using `php` or `json` as intermediate files for fetching data from server and send updates to android application but its seems to be more complex and if i wont get the permission to access the server side files , how do i manage for updates ? whether is it necessary to have permission to access the server files ?

More about the topics : if i want to syncronise the update with website , 
how do i handle it or implement it ? i am not asking any sort of coding here .

Comment: Have you considered some options allready? If so: share your thoughts, specs etc with us. What are specifics of your situation, what are the sizes, what kind of data are you going to send/recieve. Please show what effort you've put into this, so we're not retracing your own steps

Comment: your website is developer.android.com? :D

Comment: hey what you actually want i,e sync the content when you appear online or want to know that how to update the content and post to UI screen ...clarify your question more eloborately

Comment: @Nanne Hey do you give any idea about this .I know u are good at android can you just help me here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. How to fetch or retrieve data from server and post updates on android application

   > use [HTTPClient](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).
2. How to manage offline storage means whenever there is no internet connection how the data gone be updated on android application

   > I think you don't understand what offline storage means. If there is no internet connection, that's it. You are not able to update your content. Offline storage is useful if you have internet connection, but not everytime. The content you downloaded when you had internet connection can be saved to [SQLLite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) to be loaded when you don't have internet connection.
3. I am actually using php or json as intermediate files for fetching data from server and send updates to android application but its seems to be more complex and if i wont get the permission to access the server side files , how do i manage for updates ? whether is it necessary to have permission to access the server files ?

   > Create WebService as an interface. Do not let other system to be able to directly access your files. Or just create a PHP files that basically return Json or XML Data. 
   >   Other option : create an RSS.
4. More about the topics : if i want to syncronise the update with website , how do i handle it or implement it ? i am not asking any sort of coding here .

   > Create an event to start sync using HTTPClient. If there is new update, save it to SQLLite(for offline storage) and display the content. The event can be triggered during the start of your application or clicking refresh button and if Internet exist.

**Update** :

There is a new framework called [couchbase mobile](https://github.com/couchbase/mobile). You can sync the local mobile db from a couch server. You can insert/update the data locally(offline mode) and then the data can be synced also to the couch server, whenever you have internet connection. This means the need to create HTTPClient is no longer necessary.

For the database, try [cloudant](http://cloudant.com).

Comment: thanks for reply , is there any framework in android we are gone use for this one ?

Comment: HTTPClient & SQLLite is actually part of Android SDK? Try the link first and explore first.